# Close all locally opened files in a given directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to add a step to a batch process to make sure all local files have been closed in a specific directory.

Everything I can find keeps pointing me to Net Files and Openfiles, but both of these options only close open files accessed via share (not local).

I've looked at both taskkill and microsoft's handle tool, but from what I can tell this isn't the smartest way to go about this task.

Is there an equivalent to Net Files that will close files opened locally?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which OS you refer to ?

Comment: Sorry - I'm using windows server 2008R2

Comment: why not use `handle`?

Comment: I'd also recommend [`handle`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655). However, pay particular notice to the warning in the "Usage" section.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I've read a couple warnings that forcefully closing handles via handle.exe can cause system instability - So I wasn't sure if it was actually a good idea to do this on a nightly basis.  I'll try and look a little deeper at handle.

Comment: closing file handles past the BS can crash the system, no matter what tool you use.

Comment: You should rather look more into what's actually keeping those handles open. As Endoro said, the problem is not the tool you use, but that you're forcefully closing handles that an application expects to be still open. Why do you believe you need this in the first place?

Comment: The problem is pretty simple actually -  Every now and again I accidentally leave a notepad open, or a command prompt open within my build directory.  When ANT tries to delete the directory, it fails because a file or directory is open.  This leaves my build directory in a bad state.  When the build goes to run, it fails.  I want to put a fail safe in place that makes sure there is nothing open in the directory.  It's actually pretty rare that it happens -  I just wanted to put an extra step in there to make sure nothing is open.

Comment: If these were open from a network share, Net File or Openfiles would take care of this, but unfortunately it's always something that is left open directly on the server.

Answer (score 0):

you might try this with `handle` on the command line:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %a in ('handle "c:\folder"') do @for /f %b in ("%~a") do @echo handle -c %~b
```

Remove `echo` if the output looks good.